# Replacing a certain item of a for loop based on user input

Tags: loops, for-loop, input, replace

I'm still new to software engineering in general, and I have to complete the following:
There should be 6x3 box of 'O' printed out and the program should replace an 'O' to '+' based on the coordinates given by user input.
Since I missed a lot of lectures from school due to family concerns, I am not sure what kind of commands should I use, but I have a nested for loop for printing the 6x3 shape and from this point Im lost...
Any help would be much appreciated! :)

I have a nested for loop like this:

for sor in range(3):
for oszlop in range(6):
print('O', end=' ')
print()

The result:
O O O O O O
O O O O O O
O O O O O O

i.e.: User input is: 2,3
result should be:
O O O O O O
O O + O O O
O O O O O O

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @dustytrash - Based on the code, this is Python.

Comment: As a start, perhaps use a 2D list to keep track of (store) the values.  Aside, we’re not here to solve this for you.  Perhaps consult with your lecturer (or fellow course members) for the bits you’ve missed.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question in a way that will help you, because it depends on the context of your class.
If you haven't learned about creating functions yet, you should not use them. Same goes for 2d arrays and variables. Furthermore you should never use code you do not yet understand. This will lead you further down the hole you're already experiencing and require code to be writen for you at every assignment. This is because most programming assignments will build off of knowledge gained from previous ones. An answer might get you an A, but only by understanding the solution will allow you to complete future assignments without intervention.

However you've seem to have put some effort into the question, so I'll try to provide a helpful answer.

Assuming you've abstracted the user input X and Y, and the coordinates are 1-based
you can use an **if statement** to check if `sor` and `oszlop` are equal to the values.

```
width = 6
height = 3

line = ''

userInputX = 3
userInputY = 2

for sor in range(height):
    for oszlop in range(width):
        # range() function begins are 0, so take away 1 from the input from user  
        if (userInputX - 1) == oszlop and (userInputY - 1) == sor:
            line += '+ '
        else:
           line += '0 '
    print(line)
    line = ''
```

A better way, if you've learned about 2d arrays:

```
lines = []
# initialzie the array with 0's
for x in range(height):
    line = []
    for y in range(width):
        line.append('0')
    lines.append(line)
    
lines[userInputY-1][userInputX-1] = '+'
    
for a in lines:
    line = ''
    for b in a:
        line += (b + ' ')
    print(line)
```